# Replace all Social Security Number (SSN) digits with X's

Tags: sed, scripting, regular-expression

I want a sed command that will change all the numbers in all Social Security # sequences (formatted only like this **123-45-6789** or this **123456789**) to X's. Any sequence of numbers that are not formatted exactly like one of the 2 provided examples should not be affected by the `sed` command. The number sequences are all in an **info.txt** file.

**info.txt** looks like roughly like this:

```
id093: 888-88-8888
id094: 333-33-3333
id095: 123456789
id096: 987654321
This next number shouldn't be converted to X's 0123456789 nor this one 0987-65-4321
```

From looking at this page ( http://www.computerhope.com/unix/used.htm ) under "The s command," I know that this is the format I need to use:

`sed –i 's/regularexpression(s)/replacement/g' info.txt`

I am unsure how to format the `regular expression(s)` and `replacement` portions so only numbers that fit the 2 previously mentioned formats get affected (while maintaining the hyphens).

Comment: What about `0123-45-6789` or `123-45-67890`?

Comment: @choroba [Those are not valid SSNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number#Structure)

Comment: Only `###-##-####` should be accepted in the hyphens format. 9 digits only

Comment: @velkoon: But valid SSNs are parts of them.

Comment: Oh, you're saying valid SSNs are contained within your examples? That's true, but there will always be some sort of whitespace separating the SSNs from other text. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: You should edit the question to clarify how the SSNs appear in the text -- if they can be at the beginning or end of a line, or surrounded by digits, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be using GNU `sed` (`-i` extension) already:

```
sed -ri ':1
         s/(^|[^-0-9])[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}([^-0-9]|$)/\1XXX-XX-XXXX\2/g
         s/(^|[^-0-9])[0-9]{9}([^-0-9]|$)/\1XXXXXXXXX\2/g
         t1' your-file
```

(with BSD `sed`, replace `-ri` with `-Ei ''`)

That is convert the `ddddddddd` and `ddd-dd-dddd` provided they're not preceded nor followed by a decimal digit or hyphen.

With `perl` (from which GNU `sed` borrowed that `-i`):

```
perl -pi -e 's{(?<![\d-])(\d{3}-\d\d-\d{4}|\d{9})(?![\d-])}{
  $& =~ s/\d/X/gr}eg' your-file
```